# apt-get install libglapi-mesa error

Tags: apt, software-installation

I'm struggling with Ubuntu for almost 3 months now. And it never fails to drive me crazy. I'm using Ubuntu for compiling Android kernels for beaglebone black. I installed Ubuntu into a separate physical harddrive. After I finished my work with it, I disconnected that harddrive and didn't use it until today. This morning I reconnect my Ubuntu harddrive and tried to boot Ubuntu. And suprise suprise. It didn't boot up. Since I didn't care the files in harddrive, I formated it and installed a brand new Ubuntu.

Now I am following the exact steps I did before for kernel compiling. I need several packages to install for compiling an Android kernel. One of them is "libglapi-mesa" . I am using following shell command to install it:

```
apt-get install libglapi-mesa
```

But it acts differently and doesn't install the package. Here is the response of shell:

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

Note, selecting 'libglapi-mesa-lts-saucy' instead of 'libglapi-mesa'

libglapi-mesa-lts-saucy is already the newest version.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded
```

I've used the same Ubuntu 12.04.4 setup. And in the past it was installing the package I want, now it doesn't install it. It says "selecting 'libglapi-mesa-lts-saucy'" and "libglapi-mesa-lts-saucy is already the newest version." but I don't want these packages because when I try to run

```
sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
  zip curl libc6-dev libncurses5-dev:i386 x11proto-core-dev \
  libx11-dev:i386 libreadline6-dev:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 \
  libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 openjdk-6-jdk tofrodos \
  python-markdown libxml2-utils xsltproc zlib1g-dev:i386 \
  minicom tftpd uboot-mkimage expect libgl1-mesa-dri
```

It fails, because it needs 'libglapi-mesa' .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from [package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libglapi-mesa) the package libglapi-mesa in 12.04 neads one of the variants libglapi-mesa-lts-quantal or libglapi-mesa-lts-raring (or libglapi-mesa-lts-saucy within precise-updates). It seems as if these are backported versions of newer Ubuntu releases. 
It is the same for libgl1-mesa-dri. If your last command doesn't work, try to install ibgl1-mesa-dri-lts-saucy instead.

Comment: I tried to run : apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri . And it seems to work for now. Thanks.